# Able to connect AWS Redshift via dbConnect but not src_postgres

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, dplyr, rpostgresql

I am to connect to AWS Redshift using dbConnect query

```
conn_loss <- dbConnect(drv, host="hydrogen2.YOURHOST.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com", 
                 port="5439",
                 dbname="mydb", 
                 user="master_user", 
                 password=password)
```

However, when I try connecting using src_postgres

```
myRedshift <- src_postgres(dbname = "mydb",
                           host = "hydrogen2.YOURHOST.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com",
                           port = 5439,
                           user = "master_user", 
                           password = "password")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) :   RS-DBI driver: (could not connect
```

Comment: To me it looks like you pass two different things as a password argument. In the first function, you pass an object, in the second function, you pass the string "password" as a password. Is that intended?

Comment: Looks like you need to remove quotes from `port` in first example.  It should be `int`